# AMD Radeon 5770 (GV-R577UD-1G) dual VGA monitors, one not getting input win7

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, vga, amd-radeon

First off: I know this will work because I have had all the involved components set up before, but I had some help from a friend then to set that up and now I have had to format and re-install windows, thus I'm faced with this problem again.

I have a AMD Radeon 5770 (model GV-R577UD-1G) graphics card and two VGA screens. The screens are both running [VGA to DVI adapters](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/DVI-VGA-Adapter.jpg) but only one will be displayed by the computer, the other other one will show up in the screen resolution panel as connected, but the screen itself displays a "no input signal" message and goes completely black.

There is also a ghost screen appearing in the screen resolution panel.

**What I've tried:**

- Changing sockets for the screens (this computer's set-up has previously had bugs with one screen not working upon start-up, but will work when changing the socket it's plugged into on the graphics card)
- Install the drivers on the installation-disk that came with the card.
- Install the newest drivers for this graphics card.
- Windows-button + P and Extended-desktop - nothing.
- Poking at just about any setting I could find through the screen resolution panel.
- Googled the issue for 4 hours.

All other drivers are also up to date from the manufacturer's website.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Couple questions:

1. Do both screen show up during BIOS and POST

2. Does swapping inputs for the two screens yield the same results during bootup as well as when you're in the OS?

Comment: I did not try checking the BIOS or POST, but it shows up as mentioned when I enter screen resolution panel, and it shows as active unlike the ghost screen that's dead but showing. No difference in swapping the cables when computer is on or off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after sleeping on it and realising the similar questions I found here weren't true to my issue; the card supports them so I know it works, I have both monitors in the graphics card, not one on the mother-board, the computer finds the screen, it just doesn't give (correct) input to the screen.

**I slept on it and now I solved it on my own by experimenting:**

The issue seem to be that the screens are both analog and you need to enter the Catalyst software settings by right-clicking the desktop and select "Catalyst(TM) Control Centre".

This automatically let me into the set-up guide being my first time using it with **the newest drivers**. There the second screen showed up as an analog input, unlike the driver-version that came with the graphics card where it for some reason showed as digital.

This set the second screen into the projector mode (Can be accessed by pressing the windows-button + P), not extended desktop, and it works as intended now.